# Can operations on arbitrarily differentiable functions form a group?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the the set $S=${All uniary operations (all operations that perform on one function and give you another function, e.g $(x^2)'=2x$) on all arbitrarily differentiable functions}, does it form a group under the binary operation where you compose two operations (e.g. First perform $L_1$ on function $f$,we get function $g$. Then perform $L_2$ on function $g$, we get function $h$, we call this process $L_2L_1$)?

Sure the associativity is ensured, and there exists an identity operation which leaves the function intact. 

But if $L_1,L_2\in S$,is $L_2L_1$ also in the set? In other words, is it possible that after perfrom $L_1$, we get a function that can't be operated by $L_2$? If that's the case, then $L_2L_1$ is not defined, therefore $L_2L_1\notin S$. 

For every operation, does there exists an operation in the set that can undo it? For example, how do you undo $\frac d{dx}$? I don't think we're able to recover the primitive function, so we should exclude differentiations on functions, therefore integrations should be excluded too since they don't have inverses.

Comment: How do you compose two binary operations?

Comment: Can you say what you mean by a uniary operation? I don't know that term...

Comment: First operate on function f with L1, we get function g, then operate on function g with L2, we get function h. we call this process operation L3, which is denoted by L2L1.

Comment: "uniary operation" may be misspelled, but what I actually meant were all operations that perform on one function and give you another function.

Comment: If you see an unary operation as function from $C^{\infty} \to C^{\infty}$, then you can indeed compose them, but there is no reason at all these functions form a group, because a group needs an inverse (take for example $L(f) \mapsto 0$. If you take bijective operations, then yes you just get the group of permutations on $C^{\infty}$. But this is not the case even for differentiation (you lose the constant term), and integration isn't defined on the whole $C^{\infty}$.